# Getting getelementsbyclassname to work properly

Tags: javascript

I have two tags in the HTML page with the classname test. When I try to execute the following code and display the output using getelementsbyclassname, the last output is displayed twice instead of displaying the first one followed by the second.

```
var callbackTester = function (callback) {
    var tryMe = "Are you ready, ";
    callback(tryMe);
};
var createMessageHandler = function (client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.result = function (foo) {
        foo(function (msg) {
            var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test');
            for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {  
              elements[i].innerHTML = (msg + " " + this.client);
           };
        }.bind(this));
    }
};

(new createMessageHandler("John")).result(callbackTester);
(new createMessageHandler("Jason")).result(callbackTester);
```

Looked through a lot of SO questions and the implementation looks similar. What am I missing?

Comment: The current implementation updates all the elements with the class name `test`. As `Jason` is called at the last, it's updating all the element with `Jason` content. http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/epp4cLpe/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/epp4cLpe/2/

**JS:-**

```
var callbackTester = function (callback) {
    var tryMe = "Are you ready, ";
    callback(tryMe);
};
var createMessageHandler = function (client) {
    this.client = client;
    this.result = function (foo) {
        foo(function (msg) {
            var el = document.createElement("div");
            el.className = "test";
            el.innerHTML = (msg + " " + this.client);
            document.getElementById("temp").appendChild(el);
        }.bind(this));
    }
};

(new createMessageHandler("John")).result(callbackTester);
(new createMessageHandler("Jason")).result(callbackTester);
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="temp"></div>
```